# Column width not getting applied on jstree table plugin

Tags: jstree

Am using jstree with table plugin.
Column width 250 not getting applied on column 'Price' and 'Qty'.
I have given column width as 250 for column 'Price' and 'Qty', but i is not getting applied.
can you please assist on this.

```
$("div#jstree").jstree({

  core: {
    data: data
  },
  plugins: ["table","dnd","contextmenu","sort","search"],
  search: {
      case_insensitive: true,
      show_only_matches: true
    },
  // configure tree table
  table: {
    columns: [
      {width: 200, header: "Name", format: function(v) { return "<i>"+v+"</i>"}},
      {width: 250, value: "price", header: "Price", format: function(v) {if (v){ return '$'+v.toFixed(2) }}},
      {width: 250, value: "quantity", header: "Qty"}
    ],
    resizable: true,
    draggable: true,
    contextmenu: true,
    width: 900,
    height: 300
  }
});
```

Here is the fiddle.

```
http://jsfiddle.net/shmyusuf/56mxp4ov/3/
```

Comment: Second and Third columns width is not working for me too! Any fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

this table plugin has a bug.

```
            col.find(".jstree-table-cell").each(function () {
            var item = $(this),
                width;
            item.css("position", "absolute");
            item.css("width", "auto");
            width = item.outerWidth();
            item.css("position", "static");

            if (width > newWidth) {
                newWidth = width;
            }
        });

        /*you can add this code in your plugin*/ 
        var index = col.parent().children().index(col);
        var headerCol = $('.jstree-table-headerwrapper>div').eq(index);
        var headerWidth =  headerCol.width();
        if (headerWidth > newWidth) {
            newWidth = headerWidth;
        }
```

Comment: could You be more specific? :)

Comment: sorry ,i can not  speak english.
i have  updated my  source ,i think you can  see the difference.

https://github.com/Dao-Cao/jstree-table/commit/23b2ee0cb56bb7ecf030e7e66204bc055677752b

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the code has a bug. Just replace the line

```
col.find(".jstree-table-cell").each(function () {
```

with this line

```
col.children.find(".jstree-table-cell").each(function () {
```

This should help.